# Update table wp_term_taxonomy.count after INSERT INTO via SQL

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, sql

**Short description:** I've created a bunch of terms and attached them to an existing taxonomy for a certain custom-post that already exist using the SQL code below. After doing this I'd like to update wp_term_taxonomy.count . I set it to 0 (dumb?) so the new terms are not appearing in search forms (they do appear on the individual custom post though). Setting count to 1 fixes this but still 'wrong' and I'm worried this could cause issues down the line.

Answers within SQL or Wordpress will work though my coding is just above n00b status.

**My solution:** set wp_term_taxonomy.count to 1 for new terms so it'll appear across the site. I can use them in searches (important) but things like tag clouds are wrong/mis-sized (fine) and I'm worried I'll run into unknown issues.

**Details:** 
I am adding many terms to a taxonomy I have already created called 'csf_brand' for a custom post type called 'jeans'. Rather than editing each of several hundred custom posts already created I thought I'd batch them with SQL, using the 3 tables related to custom taxonomies.

First I create my new terms.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_nhyb_terms` (`term_id`, `name`, `slug`, `term_group`) VALUES
(10, 'GAP', 'gap', 0); --there's a bunch more lines like this adding in new terms
```

Next, I attach my terms to the appropriate taxonomy. 0 is not the right count but calculating this is not something I'm interested in doing if I can avoid it.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_nhyb_term_taxonomy` (`term_taxonomy_id`, `term_id`, `taxonomy`, `description`, `parent`, `count`) VALUES
(10, 10, 'csf_brand', '', 0, 0); --Here is where I could use 1 instead of 0
```

Finally, I attach the terms to my custom post types by the post ID (object_id)

```
INSERT INTO `wp_nhyb_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) VALUES
(125, 10, 0);
```

And that works. But wp_term_taxonomy.count is not 0 so they aren't appearing in my searches (e.g. I have a page that can search for brands via dropdown and they aren't an option). If I edit a custom post in my browser then save it recognizes the new term and corrects the count. But that's not a great process since I'll eventually miss something.

Comment: Have you considered `wp_insert_term` an `wp_set_object_terms`? There's no need to use raw SQL to set create and change terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run the `wp_update_term_count_now` php function after doing this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term_count_now/

Which calls the private `_update_post_term_count`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_update_post_term_count/

If you look at the source of that you will see how term counts are updated (which is done when you save a post on backend):

```
function _update_post_term_count( $terms, $taxonomy ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $object_types = (array) $taxonomy->object_type;

    foreach ( $object_types as &$object_type )
        list( $object_type ) = explode( ':', $object_type );

    $object_types = array_unique( $object_types );

    if ( false !== ( $check_attachments = array_search( 'attachment', $object_types ) ) ) {
        unset( $object_types[ $check_attachments ] );
        $check_attachments = true;
    }

    if ( $object_types )
        $object_types = esc_sql( array_filter( $object_types, 'post_type_exists' ) );

    foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) {
        $count = 0;

        // Attachments can be 'inherit' status, we need to base count off the parent's status if so.
        if ( $check_attachments )
            $count += (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->posts p1 WHERE p1.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id AND ( post_status = 'publish' OR ( post_status = 'inherit' AND post_parent > 0 AND ( SELECT post_status FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = p1.post_parent ) = 'publish' ) ) AND post_type = 'attachment' AND term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term ) );

        if ( $object_types )
            $count += (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('" . implode("', '", $object_types ) . "') AND term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term ) );

        /** This action is documented in wp-includes/taxonomy.php */
        do_action( 'edit_term_taxonomy', $term, $taxonomy->name );
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, compact( 'count' ), array( 'term_taxonomy_id' => $term ) );

        /** This action is documented in wp-includes/taxonomy.php */
        do_action( 'edited_term_taxonomy', $term, $taxonomy->name );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, use the APIs given instead of using raw SQL

To create a new term:

`wp_insert_term`

To add or set terms on an object/post/user/etc:

`wp_set_object_terms`

There's also a synonym `wp_set_post_terms` but it's just a thin wrapper around it. There's no need to write raw SQL in WordPress if you're using standard data types

Comment: Thanks Tom. Your approach is better for most users.

I'm going to leave sMyles as the accepted answer because it directly answers my question, where yours suggests a better alternative to my original problem.